# Recursive function call

Tags: python, recursion

The basic idea of my function is: I am trying to replicate the unix command "cd ../" (which causes the parent directory to be selected), however I want to be able to enter "cd ../../" (as a command line argument).

So I am attempting a recursive call. The function will find if a string contains "../" and if it does, call my function upOneDir() (which will effectively change the directory of the program to the parent) and then call itself (dotDotSlash()).

```
def dotDotSlash():
    s = sys.argv[2]
    dotDotSlash = "../"

    if (s.find(dotDotSlash) == -1):
        print "not found"

    else:
        print "found ../ at: "
        print s.find(dotDotSlash)
    upOneDir()
    dotDotSlash()
```

The function executes only once when I try to enter "cd ../../" and then gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 59, in <module>
    dotDotSlash()
  File "test3.py", line 40, in dotDotSlash
    dotDotSlash()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any ideas on why the function isn't calling itself correctly?

Comment: Use getopt its a python built-in it'll fulfils your need.

Comment: you named your variable with the same name as your function

Comment: `dotDotSlash = "../"` is string in same name `def dotDotSlash()` change variable name or funciton name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrote the reference to the function. Python doesn't differentiate between the name of a function and the name of any other object. Call `'../'` something else so it doesn't interfere.

Also, the recursive call will need to be returned, with `return dotDotSlash()`. Additionally, the whole point of a recursive function is that you send it an argument, it modifies the argument, and then it sends the modified argument to the function again, until it gets to a defined stopping point. I recommend trying to implement your function with a loop before trying to create a recursive version.

You could probably just do something along the lines of `for i in range(sys.argv[2].count('../')): upOneDir()` anyway.

Comment: This function does not need to return anything

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot of time. That for loop is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are naming the variable `dotDotSlash` with the same name of your function `dotDotSlash()`. Change the name of this variable `dotDotSlash = "../"` to something like `dotDotSlash_var = "../"`